# How to programmatically set "start printing after last page is spooled" on printers

Tags: printing, windows-server, zebra-printers, powershell-5.0

I've created over a hundred printers (*and associated queues*) on a print server, shared them, and configured them as desired (name, port, comments, location, etc) but an option I can't seem to identify a way to set is the flag on the advanced Printer Properties tab to **"start printing after last page is spooled"**.  I'm using **PowerShell** but open to whatever works.  I have dredged the net and asked the all-powerful google in every variation I can think of to locate an answer, without result.  I've also looked through Microsoft's documentation of related print management PowerShell commands (such as Add-Printer, Set-PrinterProperty, Set-Printer, and Set-PrintConfiguration) and printer-related registry settings with no luck.

I'm curious if the **-RenderingMode CSR** option for the print management commands would do it, but I can't find much documentation on the specifics of that to confirm.  Hopefully you fine folks can assist.

Help me Obi-Wan, you're my only hope...

Comment: I don't have a direct answer to your question, but can I ask what are you trying to achieve? maybe there's a workaround

Comment: I'm trying to set that property value to enabled via a script so that it could be applied to hundreds of printers in moments instead of hours via manually applying via GUI one-by-one.  Not sure how I can really elaborate or clarify that further...  It's pretty darned simple, I just don't see the property exposed in documentation I've been able to locate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-printer

The property that sets this is called **Queued**. So set `Queued = $true` through a CimInstance or through Get-WmiObject to set the print queue to *Start printing after last page is spooled*.

Comment: When I get a chance, I'll try that.  It wouldn't surprise me if good ol' WMI was the only method, but the documentation doesn't read like that's the flag that would do it.  Definition of that field from that page below.  Appears to reference printer capability, not spooler setting to fully queue in spooler before sending to printer.

Queued

Data type: boolean
Access type: Read/write
If TRUE, the printer buffers and queues print jobs.

Comment: It took me time to figure this out because I don't think Microsoft's documentation on that page does a good job explaining what setting it actually affects. I too googled around for a while (including locating this post in doing so!) and I eventually stumbled upon an obscure GitHub project that explained that `DoCompleteFirst` sets the *Print spooled documents first* property (something that the Microsoft documentation does explain correctly) and `Queued` sets the *Start printing after last page is spooled* property. Let myself and others who happen to stumble upon this page know how it goes!

Comment: For confirmation I tried setting the *Start printing after last page is spooled* property on a print queue in my system this way and it appears to have done it successfully.

GitHub project referenced in my previous comment: https://github.com/daBONDi/ansible-role-win-printer